# for fear that and lest

Tags: synonyms

Are the following sentence natural?

1. You'd better study harder **for fear that** you might fail the exam.
2. You'd better study harder **lest** you should fail the exam.

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary defines **for fear...** as "to avoid the danger of something happening." I am wondering whether this definition can explain whether the first sentence is natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My AmE ear finds your two sentences unnatural, for different reasons.

If we use **lest**, it is without **should**.

> ... lest you fail the exam
>
> ... lest he fail the exam

Your sentence is grammatical, but would probably sound more natural to a BrE speaker.

**for fear that** is an explanation for someone's actions or behavior; it refers to the *motive* for an action that has already taken place, or which takes place regularly:

> They piled up sandbags in front of the door **for fear that** the flood waters
>   might enter the house.  <sup>idiomatic</sup>
>
> Whenever it rains they pile up sandbags in front of the doors **for fear that** the flood waters might enter the houses.  <sup>idiomatic</sup>

It is not used with an action in the future of the person being spoken to:

> You had better pile up sandbags at the door **for fear that** the flood waters
>   might enter the house.  <sup>not idiomatic</sup>

or being spoken about:

> They had better pile up sandbags at the doors **for fear that** the flood waters might enter the houses.

It is unnatural to supply motives before the fact.

**lest** would work there:

> You had better pile up sandbags at the door **lest** the flood waters
>   enter the house.  <sup>idiomatic</sup>

since **lest** refers to what could happen.

Comment: I am curious if my answer is wrong in any way. Worded differently but in essence the same result I believe? I do not hear "lest" much these days in neither BrE nor AmE except Game of Thrones or such

Comment: @mplungjan: I think with your phrase "when you talk about them" you mean much the same thing as I do with "refers to the motive for an action".  Though you don't quite spell it out.

Comment: The difference is that  Tᴚoɯɐuo suggested that "lest" can be used to make suggestions.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Do you think the dictionary definition I quoted is adequate, by the way?

Comment: A single word would make it better: "*wishing* to avoid the danger of something happening"

Comment: I've found the biblical verse: "Now keep this in mind, you who have no memory of God, for fear that you may be crushed under my hand, with no one to give you help." Would you consider the use of "for fear that" in imperatives ungrammatical? The Jehovah's Witness's bible has a similar example: "Watch yourself that you do not conclude a covenant with the inhabitants of the land to which you are going, for fear it may prove itself a snare in your midst."

Comment: Also consider "Go then from this place, my friends, as quickly as you may, for fear lest you shall be involved in my misfortune, and that some day your wives shall curse me as the author of your loss,"  taken from J.H. Robinson's Readings in European History.

Comment: @Apollyon. Rely not upon the words of Jehovah as indicator of contemporary idiomatic use, for fear that you may be taken astray.

Comment: Their heretical views aside, what is there so unreliable about their language use?

Comment: I have already given you the answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

If by natural you mean idiomatic? No.

[For fear that](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+fear+that) and the synonym [lest](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lest) would be used when describing a situation

You cannot say to someone "do this for fear of something" or 
"do this lest something"

You can say "Study harder or suffer the consequences" - that may make them study harder lest you come after them.

Then when you talk about them, you can say "They studied harder for fear that  I would punish them

They can say "I studied harder lest I got punished" but lest is not in daily use except in some standard phrases like *Lest we forget*

Comment: I do believe that **lest** is used fairly often in the US South, and not just in fixed phrases.

Comment: I DO declare, Mr. Beauregard!